# Как в VK Api (Android) узнать, валиден ли AccessToken

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

**Задача**: при включении приложения проверить валидность полученного в предыдущей сессии `VKAccessToken`.

**Проблема**: не работает метод, прослушивающий изменения `AccessToken'a`.

---

После авторизации пользователя, я получаю `VKAccessToken`, через `onActivityResult` и сохраняю его в `Preferences`. Но, во время включения приложения, мне нужно как-то узнать его валидность (что будет гарантировать, что пользователь не сменил пароль или еще что-то).

Для "прослушки" изменений валидности — я запускаю слушателm `VKAccessTokenTracker`, как написано в VK Api:

```
    public class Application extends android.app.Application {
        private static final String TAG = "RostislavLOG"; //Временная переменная для откладки

        private VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
                if (newToken == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "VKAccessToken is invalid");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "VKAccessToken is valid");
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            //Инициализация VK Api
            VKSdk.initialize(this);
            vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        }
    }
```

Однако, метод `onVKAccessTokenChanged` не запускается, при включении приложения, и никак не реагирует на изменение пароля (как включенное приложение, так и только что запущенное).

---

Так как же все-таки узнать валидность `VKAccessToken`?

Comment: А как isLoggedIn метод себя ведёт после смены пароля?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, какой `isLoggined`?

Comment: Вот  этот: `VKSdk.isLoggedIn()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, почти. После того, как я вошел — говорит `true`, но когда сменил пароль — тоже `true`. Методы взаимосвязаны, по всей видимости.

Comment: Гугл молчит на сей счёт. Беглый просмотр исходников вкшного сдк тоже мне ничего не прояснил... Возможно надо проверять пробуя что-то сделать, получив ошибку с сообщением о невалидном токене и именно тогда запрашивать авторизацию?.. Может именно в этот момент сдк и поменяет своё устаревшее мнение о том, что токен валиден всё ещё.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, у меня появилась теория и идея на счет получения ответа сразу, поле запуска. Да и поддержка вк может что-то ответит. Завтра проверю.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сегодня днем.* Спокойной ночи :D.

Comment: В любом случае напишите что получится - мне и самому интересно)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мое предположение оказалось ложным... Я заметил такую последовательность: когда я запускаю приложение, `VKSdk` инициализируется в классе `Application`. После того, как я "убиваю" приложение в телефоне — оно висит в процессе, а когда я запускаю его снова — инициализация не проходит снова. Однако, когда я убиваю процесс в *Android Device Monitor* и снова запускаю его — инициализация проходит снова и мне сразу же приходит ответ! При чем процесс приложения "держит" не `VKAccessTokenTracker`...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хотя странно... С другими приложениями так же. Да и сервисом! Это Android останавливает приложения и сервисы, но, почему-то, они и дальше висят в процессах!

Comment: Андроид вообще очень странный) Чем больше в него углубляешься, тем больше в этом убеждаешься)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, но `KateMobile` же как-то проверяет валидность... И официальное приложение ВКонакте. Значит как-то можно...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, подожду ответ на только что заданный вопрос. Если не ответят — пойду методом костыля. Да и поддержка ВКонакте может что-то скажет на этот счет.